# What is a person living in a hostel called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I have heard some people say the word *hostelite* or *hostelide* but just not sure if they are proper words.

P.S. I couldn't find it in any dictionary when I googled. Hosteler might be the closest. But I was referring to student hostels. Like accommodations on the campus. According to dictionaries, hostel is a place of temporary stay for travelers or the homeless.

Comment: Welcome Alchemist!  Please add your research so our users know what steps you've already taken.

Comment: Hostel has different meanings in different parts of the world. "In India, Pakistan and South Africa, hostel also refers to boarding schools or student dormitories in resident colleges and universities." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostel
In this case I think *student resident* is appropriate.

Comment: It seems to me that if it's a student hostel they'd be called "students".

Comment: If you want to emphasize permanent (or long-term) residency  in a hostel, you can consider ***hostel-dweller.***

Comment: Student accommodations on campuses are more commonly called **dorms** (in the U.S.; abbreviated from _dormitories_) or **(student) halls (of residence)** (in the UK), rather than hostels. That doesn't necessarily help much, though, 'cause I don't think there's a common, simple term for someone who lives in dorms or halls, either. I suppose you could always be witty and call them _dormant_…

Comment: I would use their name.

Comment: I get it. So concluding all this, hosteler is not a term meant to be for students in dorms.

Comment: As regards "youth hostels" (auberges de jeunesse) in Europe, which are open to hikers, cyclists etc. - the people using them are sometimes called "youth hostellers". And young people talk about "going youth hostelling".

Comment: @HotLicks Unless you were trying to make a distinction between students who lived in the hostels and those who lived off-campus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean a [hosteller or hosteler](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hosteler) :

> - a person who stays at youth hostels (Collins)

- [Hostelite](https://dreamzandclouds.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/a-hostelite/) can be found googling, but it is not a term found in dictionaries yet. Probably a slang term.

Regarding *student hostels*,  the following [site](http://hostel.iisc.ernet.in/hostel/index.php/home/guestrules) refers to the students who live there  as *resident students*:

> - There are a limited number of well furnished guest rooms. ***Resident student members of the hostel can avail this facility*** for accommodating their parents or spouse when they visit the Institute. However, the members are required to adhere to the following rules and instructions with regard to guest rooms.

Comment: This is generally what you might call someone who is staying in hostels as part of a travelling experience. I wonder if the OP was referring to someone who specifically stays at hostels due to homelessness or vagrancy?

Comment: @Alchemist - only you know what hostels you are referring to. :)

Answer (score -2):

A person who look after the hostel students maybe a warden.